# Order not working - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT chars, pts, FIND_IN_SET( pts, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pts ORDER BY pts DESC,chars ASC) FROM table ) ) AS rank
FROM table WHERE chars = 'Ueki'
```

What i a trying to get:
I am trying to get the rank of a charecter after ordering them, alphabitical(chars) and numberical(pts).

But for some reason the oder by chars doesnt work

Table:

```
+--------------------+
|  chars   |    pts  |
+--------------------+
|   abc    |     4   |
+--------------------+
|  Ueki    |     3   |
+--------------------+
|  Ueka    |     3   |
+--------------------+
```

Results:

```
(WHERE chars = 'Ueki')
    +------------------------------+
    |  chars   |    pts  |    rank |
    +------------------------------+
    |   Ueki   |     3   |      3  |
    +------------------------------+

(WHERE chars = 'Ueka')
    +------------------------------+
    |  chars   |    pts  |    rank |
    +------------------------------+
    |   Ueka   |     3   |      2  |
    +------------------------------+
```

Comment: check FROM table WHERE chars = 'Ueki' order by rank

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Done adding sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to get the rank of a charecter after ordering them,
>   alphabetically (chars) and numerically (reps).

By `reps`, I assume you mean `pts`.

If this is the order by you want, then the clauses are in the wrong order for the `order by`:

```
SELECT chars, pts,
       FIND_IN_SET(pts,
                   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pts ORDER BY chars ASC, pts DESC)
                    FROM table
                   )
                  ) AS rank
FROM table
WHERE chars = 'Ueki';
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Does MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` support more than one `ORDER BY` condition?  I literally could not find even one example of this anywhere.  Could you find a way to do the OP's ordering using only one composite column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . It is shown in the syntax diagram for `group_concat()` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).  More importantly, it works in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/5261).

Comment: @DebanjanDhar . . . "Not working" is extremely vague and provides no information to help solve the problem.